# How to create flutter Custom Curved Navigation Drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am creating custom navigation drawer. I want add curved animation `onItemSelected`.
But I have no idea how to create curved animation effect. I have tried many plugins but could not find plugin which related with this design. Here is my example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vector_icons/flutter_vector_icons.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
MaterialApp(
  home: MyApp(),
   ),
   );
 }


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
 }

  List<bool> selected = [true, false, false, false, false];

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
List<IconData> icon = [
Feather.wind,
Feather.folder,
Feather.monitor,
Feather.lock,
Feather.mail,
];

void select(int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i == n) {
    selected[i] = true;
  } else {
    selected[i] = false;
      }
     }
   }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: 101.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff332A7C),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 110,
              child: Column(
                children: icon
                    .map(
                      (e) => NavBarItem(
                        icon: e,
                        selected: selected[icon.indexOf(e)],
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            select(icon.indexOf(e));
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                 ),
               ),
              ],
            ),
              ),
               ],
            ),
         );
        }
      }

    class NavBarItem extends StatefulWidget {
     final IconData icon;
     final Function onTap;
     final bool selected;
     NavBarItem({
     this.icon,
     this.onTap,
    this.selected,
     });
  @override
  _NavBarItemState createState() => _NavBarItemState();
  }

class _NavBarItemState extends State<NavBarItem> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
AnimationController _controller1;
AnimationController _controller2;

   Animation<double> _anim1;
  Animation<double> _anim2;
  Animation<double> _anim3;
  Animation<Color> _color;

  bool hovered = false;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller1 = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
);
_controller2 = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 275),
);

_anim1 = Tween(begin: 101.0, end: 75.0).animate(_controller1);
_anim2 = Tween(begin: 101.0, end: 25.0).animate(_controller2);
_anim3 = Tween(begin: 101.0, end: 50.0).animate(_controller2);
_color = ColorTween(end: Color(0xff332a7c), begin: Colors.white)
    .animate(_controller2);

_controller1.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
_controller2.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
 }

 @override
 void didUpdateWidget(NavBarItem oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
   if (!widget.selected) {
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
    //_controller1.reverse();
  });
  _controller1.reverse();
  _controller2.reverse();
} else {
  _controller1.forward();
  _controller2.forward();
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
    //_controller2.forward();
  });
    }
   }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    widget.onTap();
  },
  child: MouseRegion(
    onEnter: (value) {
      setState(() {
        hovered = true;
      });
    },
    onExit: (value) {
      setState(() {
        hovered = false;
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      width: 101.0,
      color:
          hovered && !widget.selected ? Colors.white12 : Colors.transparent,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
        
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            width: 101.0,
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                widget.icon,
                color: _color.value,
                size: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

[image: Example image]

I want create Navigation Drawer like this image given in above example. How can I achieve this please help me for it Thank you in advance.

Comment: Found any solution regrading this?

Comment: Not yet did you?

Comment: No I am also looking for the solution. It is possible only by custom painter. Need to learn how to do.